# How can I do a Random phrase generator using the txt file reader in Java without array

Tags: java, random, readfile

I must create a Java program that reads a .txt file and output a random phrase that the same read.

String line1,line2,line3,line4,line5,line6,line7;

```
    int n;
    Random rd = new Random();
    try{

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Phrases.txt"));
        while(br.ready()){
            line1 = br.readLine();
            line2 = br.readLine();
            line3 = br.readLine();
            line4 = br.readLine();
            line5 = br.readLine();
            line6 = br.readLine();
            line7 = br.readLine();
            n = rd.nextInt(7);
            String lines=line1+line2+line3+line4+line+line+line7;

            for(int i=n;i<n;i++) {
                System.out.println(lines);
            }
        }
        br.close();
    }catch(IOException ioe){
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
```

If I try to output any of the variables "line", it will print the phrase corresponding from the txt file.

Comment: Why not use an array or a list for the read lines?

Answer (score 0):

The code below will output a random phrase read in from a text file. It assumes each phrase is on a separate line in the file. The file can contain any number of phrases.

```
ArrayList<String> PhraseList = new ArrayList<>();
Random rd = new Random();
String PhraseStr;
int PhraseIndex;
int PhraseCount = 0;


try
{

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Phrases.txt"));
    while(br.ready())
    {
        PhraseStr = br.readLine();

        if (PhraseStr != null)
        {
            PhraseCount++;
            PhraseList.add(PhraseStr);
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }

    }
    br.close();

}
catch(IOException ioe)
{
    ioe.printStackTrace();
}        

PhraseIndex = rd.nextInt(PhraseCount);

System.err.println(PhraseList.get(PhraseIndex));
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped me a lot!!
I took some time to learn some arrayList and I managed to understand it... Way easier than what I was trying to do.